Place the caret at the beginning of the JTextArea after pasting text
I would like the caret of a JTextArea to be positioned at the beginning of the first line after pressing CTRL+V. I have tried this code but it does not work, however, I noticed that by replacing the key combination with, for example, CTRL+J (KeyEvent.VK_V ---> KeyEvent.VK_J) and using it after pasting the text, the code works. How can I solve this problem?
textArea.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
        if (evt.isControlDown() && evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_V) {
            textArea.setCaretPosition(0);
        }
    }
});


Doing so would violate the 'Principle of Least Surprise' and might annoy your users. It certainly would surprise (and annoy) me. Ctrl+Home is the correct gesture to get to where you want after paste. Because it's correct, you don't have to write it

your keyPressed is probably being called before the text is copied... try keyReleased or use SwingUtilities.invokeLater

Or maybe try key bindings rather than a KeyListener.

I agree with g00se here.  Don’t make your text area behave in a different manner from all other text areas in all other applications (including the text box where I’m typing this comment).  You’ll just irritate your users.  No one likes being tricked by software.

@VGR I will do this. After all, it is not a very important function.
